# MySQLdb query command, not fetching correct database (python)

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

fixed: just using mysql.connector package now.

i am a few programming with python now and i wanted to create a use login/logout system with a database linked to a self created web platform for managment, logging, etc... 
now i wanted to perform a query to get all users from my database but for some reason im not able to get any results i tried:

```
    # as requested, connector method.
    def initiate_connection(self):
        return MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "", "tester")
    # This works ! 
    def get_database_version(self):
        db = self.initiate_connection()  # Instantiate db connection
        curs = db.cursor()               # Server sided cursors - ref more info: https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/user_guide.html#cursor-objects
        curs.execute("SELECT VERSION();")# Query command
        data = curs.fetchone()           # Fetch result.
        db.close()                       # Close conn
        return data

    # This doesnt? :(
    def get_users(self):
        db = self.initiate_connection()    # Instantiate db connection
        curs = db.cursor()                 # Server sided cursors - ref more info: https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/user_guide.html#cursor-objects
        curs.execute("SELECT name FROM users")# Query command
        data = curs.fetchone()             # Fetch result.
        db.close()                         # Close conn
        return data
```

But i get an uknown column error, so i tried selecting everything to see what i get from that result: Nonetype, Also ! i am able to retrieve version from database so i assume im connected properly.
Im pretty clueless in what im doing wrong here any ideas?

Also db structure is:

```
db->tester
table->users
   - id
   - name
   - password
   - salt
   - email
```

Edit: 
Actual error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Programmas\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "D:\Programmas\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/oj/PycharmProjects/RegisteryHandeler/DatabaseHandler.py", line 25, in <module>
    print(database_handler().get_users())
  File "C:/Users/oj/PycharmProjects/RegisteryHandeler/DatabaseHandler.py", line 18, in get_users
    curs.execute("SELECT name FROM users")# Query command
  File "C:\Users\oj\PycharmProjects\RegisteryHandeler\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 209, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Users\oj\PycharmProjects\RegisteryHandeler\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 315, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\oj\PycharmProjects\RegisteryHandeler\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 239, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'")
```

Comment: are you getting connected to the right database? and can you paste the actual error that you are seeing on the screen?

Comment: please also share actual code (i.e., arguments to `initiate_connection()` and its definition), as well as `describe users` output

Comment: @richyen I asssume so, im able to retrieve database version, updated post with connection method :)

Comment: I know this might be a dumb question, but is the column really 'name' and not something like ' name' (with a space or other non-print char)?  I'm asking because I've seen situations (and if you google for your error `1054`, you'll see that others have encountered similar issues)

Comment: you could use tools like [DBevar](https://dbeaver.io/) or [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/) to check what you have in database.

Comment: in some MySQL modules you could run query with `*` - `curs.execute("SELECT * FROM users")` and after that `print(curs.description)` to get information about columns in table.